# Back to back MOSFETs and current sensing

Tags: mosfet, current-measurement, square

I am looking into a circuit which has to do the following. A square wave goes in and a square wave goes out. I need to measure the current of the outgoing side because it is likely that the the load may be shorted. If the current exceeds 2.5 A for longer than 50 ms, I need to shut the outgoing wave off and a led must burn so I can see that there is a shortcircuit. The off situation has to last about 5 seconds before a new attempt is made to turn the system on again.

To turn the outgoing wave on and off, I want to use the back to back mosfet circuit which I found online. I believe that this part of the the circuit will work.

The current sensing is what bothers me. The general idea is that the current running through the load is leaded through R_SHUNT via rectifier D3. So the current through the shunt is always in the same direction. I believe that rectifier D4 will cause problems.

If pin 2 of DCC_IN is high and pin 1 is LOW. The current will flow through R_LOAD to the left upper diode of D3, to R_SHUNT and than instead of going through D3 again and the mosfets, the current will propably bypass this via bottem right diode of D4.

If pin 2 of DCC_IN is low and pin 1 is HIGH. The current will flow through the mosfets, through the upper right diode of D3, through R_SHUNT and than through the bottem left diode of D4 causing a direct short.

Assuming I am correct about the the current flows. Bridge D4 has to go. But if D4 is gone, can I still feed my voltage regulator and 5 V line?

[image]

The other circuit I drew, uses an ACS712 current sensor. I believe that this circuit might work, but will it? I am aware that the circuit needs some extra capacitors and schottky diodes (to relieve the internal diodes of the MOSFETs)

Will the second circuit work like I want? And if not, can I make it to work or should I do something else?

[image]

The load itself exist out of model trains. These can draw more than the maximum allowed current during accelarations (DC motor run currents).

A digital central typically cuts the power when a short circuit lasts longer than 50~100ms. This circuit needs to react slightly faster than the digital central to prevent the central from powering everything down. Essentially this circuit is intended to act as a digital fuse to prevent entire layouts from powering down and to identify the location of the shortcircuit. I could probably also live with a current of max 1A.

Comment: Are the 2.5 A and 50 ms critical in your application? Have you considered a PTC/Polyfuse?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, the circuit that you have selected is designed to switch AC and may be more complex than you need.

Comment: The load itself exist out of modeltrains. These can draw more than the maximum allowed current during accelaration. A digital central typically cuts the power when a short circuit lasts longer than 50~100ms. The circuit needs to react slightly faster than the digital central This circuit is indeed intended to act as a fuse to prevent entire layouts from powering down and to identify the location of the shortcircuit. I could probably also live with a current of max 1A. I will look into the Polyfuse

Comment: Please can you edit new information into your question rather than posting it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece together the full question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? My only goal is to measure the current draw, cut off the power after 50ms and indicate where I have to search for the shortcircuit. And this circuit is designed to do just that and nothing else. I can't switch with triacs, relays are less suited than the mosfets, and the ACS712 seems like the perfect tool for the job

Comment: @RoyC you are aware I am switching an AC squarewave? I feared that triacs, SRC and SSR might cause troubles because of the square not being a sine